# Can a stylesheet change text color in a QPlainTextEdit?

Tags: qt, qt5, qtstylesheets

I'm using the following stylesheet on a QPlainTextEdit

```
QPlainTextEdit:focus {
    color:red;
}
```

But the text color doesn't change on focus.

However if I use this:

```
QPlainTextEdit:focus {
    background-color: red;
}
```

it works...

This is the whole stylesheet:

```
QPlainTextEdit {
    background-color:#3a3a3a;color:#EEE;border:1px;border-style:solid;border-color:#999;
}

QPlainTextEdit:focus {
    background-color:#DDD;color:#111;border:1px;border-style:solid;border-color:#111;
    selection-background-color: #2222FF; selection-color:white;
}
```

When I click on the QPlainTextEdit it changes its background color (correctly) from 3a3a3a to #DDD but, it doesnt' change its text color from #EEE to #111.

Comment: Wow Qt has stylesheets now? That's kind of cool!

Comment: @Blindy It had them since Qt 4.2 :) Alas, they are not superbly useful in the modern UIs based on Qt Quick. They are only implemented for the widget system. The basic style system, used by Qt Quick to style the controls, doesn't use stylesheets.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've got a solution for your issue and using a `QPlainTextEdit`. It works also with `QTextEdit` widgets.

The idea is to install an `eventFilter` for that `QPlainTextEdit` and check if it's receiving or not the focus. Depending on that, you could set the required style.

I'll explain myself using some lines of code:

**mainwindow.h (we have a QPlainTextEdit in the ui file)**

```
#ifndef MAINWINDOW_H
#define MAINWINDOW_H

#include <QtWidgets>

#include "ui_mainwindow.h"

class MainWindow : public QMainWindow
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    MainWindow();

    Ui::MainWindow ui;

private:
    bool eventFilter(QObject * object, QEvent * event);
};

#endif
```

**mainwindow.cpp**

```
#include <QtWidgets>

#include "mainwindow.h"

MainWindow::MainWindow()
{
    ui.setupUi(this);
    ui.plainTextEdit->installEventFilter(this);
}

bool MainWindow::eventFilter(QObject *object, QEvent *event)
{
    if (object == ui.plainTextEdit)
    {
        if (event->type() == QEvent::FocusOut)
        {
            ui.plainTextEdit->setStyleSheet("color: white; background-color: black;");
        } else if (event->type() == QEvent::FocusIn) {
            ui.plainTextEdit->setStyleSheet("color: red; background-color: white;");
        }
        return false;
    }    
    return false;
}
```

Comment: and BTW, I tried your code but it didn't work and I'm really sure there are no conflicts as this is the only QPlainTextEdit I have and the only rules for QPlainTextEdits

Comment: @StephenH.Anderson I undeleted & updated my answer :) I hope this will help you.

Comment: Actually your answer works perfectly! However, I'm confussed, why does it work if we are actually applying a stylesheet which, according to Kuba Ober wouldn't work because of the richtext format? Thanks

Comment: Well, in your original question you had a `QPlainTextEdit` where the color was being applied via stylesheets. The problem was in the `:focus` state as you stated some days ago. Changing text color in the `:focus` state works for some widgets (like `QLineEdit`) but doesn't work in `QFrame` and inherited classes like `QAbstractScrollArea`, `QTextEdit` or `QPlainTextEdit` (cont. below)

Comment: (cont) Sincerely, I don't know the answer :(, but I have a guess. I do think is due to `QTextEdit` or `QPlainTextEdit` are widgets more complex. I mean the text is inside or contained in other widgets. In fact, `QTextEdit` or `QPlainTextEdit` allow the user to enter rich (HTML) text. Maybe in the `:focus` state the `color` property cannot change the corresponding code for the HTML. Or maybe this is just a bug ;)

Comment: Sounds like a bug to me. But it's nice that, at least, I got it working. Thanks so much for your help guys.

Answer (score 1):

Given that a `QPlainTextEdit` displays, somewhat counterintuitively, rich text, there's no single text color to speak of. The `QTextDocument` is the source of text color information, and you can have multiple colors within the document.

The `setPlainText()` is a convenience method that uses the plain text to create a `QTextDocument` rich text representation of it.

It is essentially impossible for `QPlainTextEdit` to make any use of the `color` property of the style, since there is no single text color to change.

Comment: Kuba, thanks, that sounds interesting... is there some other TextEdit I could use for this? I don't need richtext I would like to achieve the effect from my stylesheet (working perfectly on QLineEdits)

Comment: @StephenH.Anderson You can style a dynamic property, let's say `qproperty-color` instead, and install an event filter on the widget to act on the `QDynamicPropertyChangeEvent` by iterating over the document and changing the text color of every block individually. It's a rather non-intrusive change that allows you to keep using the stylesheet, and doesn't require any subclassing of the `QPlainTextEdit`.

Comment: Wow... that sounds difficult for the simple task I was trying to achieve. It's crazy that there is not a simple textbox one can style like one styles a QLineEdit.

Comment: @StephenH.Anderson Why don't you use a `QTextEdit`? (BTW, I deleted my answer. It was useless)

Comment: I was using it and that didn't work either. How can I achieve the effect with that one?

Comment: @StephenH.Anderson "that sounds difficult for the simple task" We're talking a dozen lines of code. Try implementing it and you'll see. It's as easy as it can be, really.

Comment: @KubaOber I've actually used Tarod's solution and it works perfectly, I don't understand why, though.

Comment: @StephenH.Anderson Perhaps I was wrong :) Experimental results in this case are where it's at.